# Img tag src issues

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image

I am having trouble using the img tag in a react app.

My file structure looks like this:

```
Project
 |    
 +-- assets
 |  |  
 |  \-- pic.png
 |    
 +-- views
 |  |  
 |  |-- Home
 |     |
 |     |-- index.js
 |     \-- index.css
```

I have an `<img>` tag in views/Home/index.js

the specific line I use is:

`<img src="../../assets/pic.png" alt="pic"/>`

But it says it can not find the file. However, if I use a `<div>`, instead of an `<img>` tag, and use css to get the file from views/Home/index.css:

```
.pic-container {
  background-image: url("../../assets/pic.png");
}

<div className="pic-container"/>
```

It works fine.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React, you usually need to either require the image or import it into your component.

```
<img src={ require("../../assets/pic.png") } alt="pic"/>
```

Or..

```
import pic from "../../assets/pic.png"
...
<img src={pic} alt="pic"/>
```